# How to delete additional days added by pandas resample?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling

I have a pandas df with tick data, with index as `datetime64[ns]` I want to resample this data into 5 minute intervals like this: `price_5min = price.price.resample('5T').ohlc().between_time('09:00:00, '16:20:00')`

It works, however it adds weekends and holidays to the new timeseries, which I need to remove. I'm not following US (or any other standard holiday calendar). I just want to remove days not in the original `price` df.

Index is not unique, many cases of same timestamp. Pandas version 0.20.1

What I have tried:

1) dropna(): I have rows with NANs that I need to ffill, so this will not work.

2) price.index.difference(price_5min.index): Gives me all the tick dates, not the day dates.

3) price.index.date.difference(price_5min.index.date): Does not work as index.date is a numpy.ndarray

4) price != price_5min: Error: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

5) price.index != price_4min.index: Error: Lengths must match to compare

Suggested logic to solve my problem:

a) Somehow compare the day dates in the two dataframes and delete based on this, but how?

b) Remove days with no variance, but how?

c) The obvious that I have not thought of (most likely..)

df price looks like this:

```
                     price  quantity
time                                
2016-06-15 16:19:20  29.85     429.6
2016-06-15 16:19:20  29.85      65.6
2016-06-15 16:19:20  29.85    1351.4
2016-06-15 16:19:30  29.70     729.4
2016-06-15 16:19:30  29.70     287.0
2016-06-15 16:19:30  29.70     219.4
2016-06-15 16:19:49  29.70      47.4
2016-06-15 16:19:52  29.70      11.8
2016-06-16 09:01:42  29.05     350.0
2016-06-16 09:01:42  29.10     189.4
2016-06-16 09:01:45  29.05      33.6
2016-06-16 09:01:54  29.05      33.6
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) and [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
diffs = np.setdiff1d(price_5min.index.date, price.index.date))
df = price_5min[~np.in1d(price_5min.index.date, diffs]
```

Another solutions with [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) or[`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
dates = price.index.floor('D')
dates_5min = price_5min.index.floor('D')
df = price_5min[~dates_5min.isin(dates_5min.difference(dates))]
```

---

```
dates = price.index.to_period('D')
dates_5min = price_5min.index.to_period('D')
df = price_5min[~dates_5min.isin(dates_5min.difference(dates))]
```

Comment: Thank you too. Btw, very nice question and huge research, it is super.  Nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Fast solution:

```
price_5min=price.groupby(price.index.Date).resample('5T').ohlc()
price_5min.index = price_5min.index.droplevel(0)
```